# How to bypass devise model password in active_admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise, activeadmin

I have a devise user model that needs to be editable in active_admin. Is there any way to bypass the need to update the password of that model every time its saved. It would be nice for admin users to be able to update user accounts without needing to know or change their passwords.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting this in you user model (these are devise overrides...)

```
def password=(new_password)
  return '' if new_password.blank?
  @password = new_password
  self.encrypted_password = password_digest(@password) if @password.present?
end

def password_required?
  !persisted? || !password.blank? || !password_confirmation.blank?
end
```

good luck. Now, if you keep the password input fields both empty, it should work.